# iOS UNUserNotificationCenter didReceiveNotificationResponse only run code if app is open in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Is it possible to conditionally run code if the app is `inactive` or in the `background`.

These are the 2 scenarios:

- If the app is in the background or inactive I **do want** to run this code block.
- If the app is killed and pressing the notification starts the app I **do not** want to run this code block.

Here is my code:

```
// Push notification received in background
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler {
  NSDictionary *userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo;

  [[SEGAnalytics sharedAnalytics] receivedRemoteNotification:userInfo];

  if ([HSBeacon isBeaconPushNotification:userInfo]) {
    UIApplication *applicaiton = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    // @todo Do not run if app was killed
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive || application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
      NSString *helpScoutBeaconID = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"HelpScoutBeaconID"];
      HSBeaconSettings *settings = [[HSBeaconSettings alloc] initWithBeaconId:helpScoutBeaconID];
      [HSBeacon handlePushNotification:userInfo beaconSettings:settings];
    }
    // End of conditional code
  }

  completionHandler();
}
```

I've tried using:

```
    UIApplication *applicaiton = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive || application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
      ...
    }
```

But this fires when the app is killed, inactive or in the backgorund.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @ScottPetit for you answer! I had to change a few things, but got it working with:

`AppDelegate.h`

```
// Use a local variable to determine if we deeplink to help scout chat
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL launchedFromPushNotification;
```

`AppDelegate.m`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSDictionary *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
  if (notification) {
    self.launchedFromPushNotification = YES;
  } else {
    self.launchedFromPushNotification = NO;
  }

  ...
}


// Push notification received in foreground
 - (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler{
  self.launchedFromPushNotification = NO;
}

// Push notification received in background
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler {
  NSDictionary *userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo;

  if ([HSBeacon isBeaconPushNotification:userInfo] && !self.launchedFromPushNotification) {
    NSString *helpScoutBeaconID = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"HelpScoutBeaconID"];
    HSBeaconSettings *settings = [[HSBeaconSettings alloc] initWithBeaconId:helpScoutBeaconID];
    [HSBeacon handlePushNotification:userInfo beaconSettings:settings];

    self.launchedFromPushNotification = NO;
  }

  completionHandler();
}
```

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

It feels like there must be a better way to do this, but one way that I think would work is keeping a local variable that you set in:

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler;
```

That delegate is only called if the application is currently in the foreground, so if you had a property like

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL receivedWillPresentNotification;
```

then you could potentially implement this like

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler {
  // Whatever other logic you have here
  self.receivedWillPresentNotification = YES;
}

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler {
  NSDictionary *userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo;

  [[SEGAnalytics sharedAnalytics] receivedRemoteNotification:userInfo];

  if ([HSBeacon isBeaconPushNotification:userInfo] && self.receivedWillPresentNotification) {
      NSString *helpScoutBeaconID = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"HelpScoutBeaconID"];
      HSBeaconSettings *settings = [[HSBeaconSettings alloc] initWithBeaconId:helpScoutBeaconID];
      [HSBeacon handlePushNotification:userInfo beaconSettings:settings];
  }

  self.receivedWillPresentNotification = NO;
  completionHandler();
}
```

Again there's probably a better solution, related to checking for notifications in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and checking the state of the application there that you could then store, but *I think* you could potentially use the other `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` methods as a proxy.